# When does "Want to improve this post?" appear?

Tags: support, answers

I just saw [above an answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/158646/25229) a banner I did not see before:

[image]

When is this banner triggered? Is this a specific flag placed on the answer (manually by someone)?
(It is certainly not automatic as plenty of answers do not have any links/sources/citations.)

Comment: In this specific instance I applied the notice along with a comment since on first reading it sounded like the answer disagreed with the others. A few comments and flags also read it the same way. The answer actually *is* in line with the others, it just has a different take on "force". But since the answer is still incredibly bare-bones and lacking meaningful detail I have kept the notice in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186087/295232). They can only be added (and removed) by ♦ moderators. The Workplace has three 'standard' answer notices and a fourth Workplace-specific one, as can be seen in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/1240483/answer-notices); this is the 'Needs citation' one.

I'm a moderator on three other sites in the network, and sometimes add these if a post gets flagged as very low quality but might be salvageable with some editing by either the author of the post or the community.